# jquery - how to escape html to prevent XSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using laravel, when a user sends a text message, it may contain some malicious code. When I use `{{}}` it will show me the exact text the user has sent. If he has sent

```
<script>alert("malicious")</script>
```

it will show exactly the same and it's good, but when I use jquery ajax, I put the fetched data to some variables within some html tags and lastly append all of them to a main tag like so:

```
   data = '';
    //loop starts here // some otger codes deleted for cleanness
    data += "<h2>"+response.name+"</h2>";
    data += "<p>"+response.description+"</p>";
    $('#mydata').html(data);
```

and now the problem is that if I use `html()` the user malicious code will be executed and if I don't, the result will not be shown as html.

I guess I should do something with `$.parseHTML`, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to encode the data.

```
$('#mydata').text(data);
```

EDIT: To create the content of #mydata you can use

```
$('#mydata')
  .html("")
  .append($("<h2></h2>").text(response.name))
  .append($("<p></p>").text(response.description))
```

Comment: as i said if i use `text()` it wont show the style of html tag but simple text. I want h2 and p tags not to be shown as simple rext but the others.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, you mentioned a good idea but my case is some how different. I have lots of data to be fetched. One part that can't be done with your approach is here:

Comment: data += '<span class="mdi mdi-information" data-question="'+data_question+'"' data-answer="'+data_answer+'">';

Comment: i think it is something like PDO binding params.

Comment: You can even do this using the jQuery functions rather than generating the html. I strongly recommend this to you so your code is robust and safe!
`$("<span></span>")
        .addClass("mdi mdi-information")
        .data({
            "question": data_question,
            "answer": data_answer
        });`

Answer (score 1):

you **cannot** render user data as HTML and escape it into safe way in the same time.
You may assume that some god-level regex could help you to drop just attributes but not tags. Unfortunately there are so many ways to inject JS into markup then you will never be sure.

So you have just few options:

1. ignore risks at all
2. escape all the things (either using jQuery's text() or escaping on backend side with htmlspecialchars()
3. use non-HTML markup that is translated to HTML by simple rules in controlled way

Comment: my bad, did not get that in this specific case it is not required to keep user data's formatting. So answer is "in general", while answer above is definitely more applicable for that case

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar scenario in of the project I worked. We used to get html content from server side which should be appended to DOM using Jquery. Before adding it to Add, we wanted to validate the HTML content we received from Server to safe guard the XSS security issues. Following is the generic method to encode the HTML content,

```
function htmlEncode(source) {
  return $("<div>").text(source).html();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this to remove  tags...

```
$('#mydata').text(data).replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

read more on this post
[Todo List Sanitizing Input jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274401/todo-list-sanitizing-input-jquery)